# Selecting textbox makes page collapse under itself

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to create a very basic mobile application and having issues with keeping my page layout correct. When I click on the textbox it makes the textboxes collapse instead of staying in positions, any help would be of use.

I've added some images below that hopefully makes my situation easier to understand

Page without selecting textbox
[image: Page without selecting textbox]

Page when selecting textbox
[image: Page when selecting textbox]

Comment: That's probably `flex-shrink`.  Use the dev tools to debug your layout.

Comment: Any code snippets would be appreciated...